# How to give disable feel to main window on showing child window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, showdialog

How to give disable feel to main window on showing child window in wpf

I used showdialog() to disable mainwindow and show the child window... i need disable visual effect( i mean a gray color effect) to the main window until close the child window...

Comment: do you mean like a modal window where you can't swap back to the parent ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [Window.Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.window.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property of the Child window to the Mainwindow before the ShowDialog() Method.

```
childwindow.Owner = mainWindow;
```

**Edit**: This results not in something like a gray style, this results in the Windows-Default Blinking-Taskbar behavior when you try to interact with the Mainwindow.